# Kafka connect: How to handle database schema/table changes

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Wondering if there is a documented process on how to handle database schema changes. I am using Debezium source connector for postgres and confluent JDBC Sink connector to replicate database changes. I need to do some changes in database as below

1. Add new columns to existing table
2. Modify database column type and update name.

I am not sure what is the best way to do this. Solution that I can think if is

1. Stop source connector
2. Wait for sinks to consume all messages
3. Upgrade the databases
4. Start source and sink connector

Answer (score 1):

Debezium will automatically add new fields in the record schema for new columns. So you would update your consumer and downstream systems first to prepare for those events. No need to stop the source...

If you change types and names, then you might run into backwards incompatible schema changes, and these operations are generally not recommended. Instead, always add new columns but "deprecate" and dont use the old ones. After you are done reading events from those old columns in all other systems, then drop those columns.